# Implement a big service with multiple endpoints or just one contract?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, service, soa

I'm building a SOA Backend and a MVC frontend and let them communicate via WCF.
But my service becomes big and a bit cluttered.
What is the best practice for a big service?
Is it better to have multiple endpoints and add multiple service references in the frontend?
Or implementing the ServiceContract in one class and create new classes to divide the responsibilities?
Or is there a better way to handle with big services?

This is my current project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based on responsibilities, you can split it into multiple/meaningful/manageable WCF services. 
Multiple endpoints will be helpful only if you are going to use multiple bindings/protocols. By default WCF services are single threaded. If your WCF code is thread safe, you can make your WCF services to support multi-thread.